# Powershell foreach loop through a list that is split from user input

Tags: powershell, foreach, string-formatting

I have this here for loop:

```
$fromInput = 1
$toInput = 99

for ($i = $fromInput; $i -le $toInput; $i++) {
            
    $destinationDir = '\\pc' + '{0:d5}' -f @($i) + "\$shareName\$dupDir"
    $netUseDir = '\\pc' + '{0:d5}' -f @($i) + "\$shareName"
    $passObj = 'pass@' + '{0:d3}' -f @($i)
        
    }
```

So it would loop through PC's from 1 to 99 but what I need now is to loop through a list of numbers that User inputs that are split

I am trying to do that with a foreach loop but it is not working for me like the one in the for loop:

```
$userInput = Read-Host "Input numbers divided by a comma [", "]"
$numberList = $userInput.split(", ")

foreach ($i in $numberList) {

    $destinationDir = '\\pc' + '{0:d5}' -f @($i) + "\$shareName\$dupDir"
    $netUseDir = '\\pc' + '{0:d5}' -f @($i) + "\$shareName"
    $passObj = 'pass@' + '{0:d3}' -f @($i)

    }
```

How do I make a foreach loop that takes the $userInput, splits it into $numberList and then loops for each of the numbers in the $numberList the way it is shown above.
I much appreciate your help as always!

Comment: If I'm understanding this correct then you just need to change the ```for``` into ```foreach```

Comment: "but it is not working for me like the one in the for loop" - well, how _is it working_? You're the only one who can see your screen, please don't make us guess what your problem is :-)

Comment: Well, apologies, forgot to mention that. The way it is working is that it does not append the 0-s to the conc of the share name location. Meaning when the user enters 1, 2, 3... the conc for the full share name should be '\\pc00001\$shareName\$dupDir' and instead it is like: "'\\pc1\$shareName\$dupDir'. In the for loop the concatenation was as it was supposed to be.

Comment: I've fixed the `for` / `foreach` problem to prevent a distraction, given that the real problem with the second loop is the _lack of zero-padding_ of the numbers in the formatted string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you are applying formatting (`d5`) to a string that is intended for an integer type. You can simply cast to `[int]` to get the desired result.

```
foreach ($i in $numberList) {

    $destinationDir = '\\pc' + '{0:d5}' -f [int]$i + "\$shareName\$dupDir"
    $netUseDir = '\\pc' + '{0:d5}' -f [int]$i + "\$shareName"
    $passObj = 'pass@' + '{0:d3}' -f [int]$i

    }
```

`Read-Host` reads data as a `[string]`. If that data needs to be a different type for whatever reason, a conversion will be needed whether that be implicit or explicit.

Answer (score 2):

First, for user input, I recommend you use something like this:

```sh
$userInput = Read-Host "Input numbers divided by a comma [", "]"
try
{
    [int[]]$numberList = $userInput.split(',')
}
catch
{
    'Input only numbers separated by commas.'
    break
}
```

To explain why `[int[]]` is there and why a `try {...} catch {...}` statement:

We are attempting to convert a `string` into an `array` and convert the resulting elements into `int`. As a result we should be getting an array of integers, if this was not the case, meaning if the user inputs something different than numbers separated by commas, we would get an error which is captured and handled by the `catch` block.

In this case, converting the strings to integers is needed by showing you a simple example:

```sh
PS /> '{0:d5}' -f '1' # String formatting on a string
1

PS /> '{0:d5}' -f 1 # String formatting on an integer
00001
```

---

Now for looping, here are the 3 easy alternatives I see:

- With `for` loop:

```sh
for($i=$numberList[0];$i -le $numberList.Count;$i++)
{
    $destinationDir = "\\pc{0:d5}\$shareName\$dupDir" -f $i
    $netUseDir = "\\pc{0:d5}\$shareName" -f $i
    $passObj = 'pass@{0:d3}' -f $i
}
```

- With `foreach` loop:

```sh
foreach($i in $numberList)
{
    $destinationDir = "\\pc{0:d5}\$shareName\$dupDir" -f $i
    $netUseDir = "\\pc{0:d5}\$shareName" -f $i
    $passObj = 'pass@{0:d3}' -f $i
}
```

- With `ForEach-Object` loop:

```sh
$numberList | ForEach-Object {
    $destinationDir = "\\pc{0:d5}\$shareName\$dupDir" -f $_
    $netUseDir = "\\pc{0:d5}\$shareName" -f $_
    $passObj = 'pass@{0:d3}' -f $_
}
```